# How can I avoid being disarmed by Draugr bosses?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I decided to play through Skyrim again, and since I've already tried a thief and a mage I figured I'd make a melee character this time through. Things are going relatively well, until I found the named Draugr at the end of the Forsaken Cave.

Every time I try to fight him, he opens by disarming me, which I can't seem to dodge in the restricted space available, and then he and his minions beat the tar out of me while I'm searching the ground for my weapon.

I know it's possible to avoid the Disarm shout projectile, but when that's difficult to do in a confined space. Is there any other way to avoid being disarmed?

Comment: Maybe wards (never wasted my time on them) or the Become Ethereal shout.

Comment: I know it's not the answer you're looking for but you could equip a back-up weapon then find your main weapon after the fight when you've a chance to look without being killed.

Comment: How about a silence spell?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm going to use @Alice Rees's idea and make it better. Go into the fight with your *Decoy Weapon* equipped, let the boss disarm you, and then equip your *Primary Weapon*. Proceed to slay the boss. Thank me later.

Answer (score 1):

You could always try to get Lydia or some other follower to tank for you, that's usually what I do.

Answer (score 1):

You can return at a higher level. According to the [wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Disarm), the full power disarm shout only works against characters up to level 30. Personal experience indicates that the draugrs never use the disarm shout after you are pretty high level.

Also according to the wiki: daedric artifacts (except dawnbreaker) are unaffected by the shout. So, you can use Volendrung against the boss instead.

Finally, if you can sheath your weapon as the shout is being casted.

Answer (score 0):

Tower of Strength (heavy armor perk) and the perk Force without Effort (meditations on the words of power) reduce stagger by a combined 75% which is an effective deterrent to being disarmed. Though my immunity to being disarmed in every playthrough may also have something to do with cushioned, since it reduces environmental damage (rockslides, swinging mammoth skull traps, etc) and not just fall damage since fall damage is environmental damage and not it's own form of damage.

Answer (score -2):

Your should equip the weakest weapon you have, then let him disarm you, then equip the strongest weapon you have. Hit him with a unrelenting force, hit him while his down.

Comment: This is pretty much the exact same as the accepted answer

Comment: how to defeat vokun if u r a vampire?

Comment: @samkelo If you have a different question, ask it using the Ask Question button top right